# EF Database Initializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to be able to specify via web.config whether to drop the entire database via EF or not so I created a simple pattern to do so. First I created two classes as follows:

```
public class AppDbInitializerDropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AppDbContext> {}

public class AppDbInitializerDropCreateDatabaseAlways : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppDbContext> {}
```

On each class, I override the `Seed` method to put in data initializer

```
protected override void Seed(AppDbContext context) {
        //This contains all data to be initialised on the database
        new AppDbDataInitializer();
}
```

I call these classes accordingly via a piece of code:

```
public static void Initialize() {
    var dropModeConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseDropMode"];
    var dropMode = DatabaseDropMode.NoDrop;

    if (dropModeConfig == "DropCreateDatabaseAlways")
        dropMode = DatabaseDropMode.DropCreateDatabaseAlways;

    if (dropModeConfig == "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges")
        dropMode = DatabaseDropMode.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges;

        Drop(dropMode);
}
```

This is working fine on my previous projects. But on my latest one, it is giving me this error:

`Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final method`

What's even weirder is if I comment out the code that calls my initialiser, my `DbContext` class is being called on the background.

Comment: Probably shoudn't have that ability in a config file

Comment: You might consider just [writing your own custom initializer](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm) which can read your config file, check if the database exists, check if the model is compatible, etc. and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Agree with @SteveGreene, custom initializer will give you not only ability to select strategy, but this also will give you ability to create stored procedures and lot of other custom things.